# Python Email script

Tags: python, email, outlook

I found a script to tinker with to send to users. I'm having troubles on setting the body of the email to the word doc as well as pulling the email address from the excel sheet.

The recipients have to change to email addresses of the users as well ex. user1@email.com, user3@email.com, user3@email.com that are all in separate cells as well as alter email bodies with the user's email and password containing in the email as plain text.

Heres the code:

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch, constants

const=win32com.client.constants
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "Subject"
newMail.BodyFormat = 2 # olFormatHTML https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa219371(v=office.11).aspx
body = "path to word doc"
newMail.HTMLBody = body

newMail.To = "email address"
newMail.display(True)
newMail.Send()
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overfloe. This is a little bit vague, what is the specific question you would like help with? What are you specifically trying to do?

Comment: Hi Nathan, so there are user names/email addresses that are to be sent to users in an email with their passwords, but the email address and passwords are in seperate cells in an excel sheet. Another thing is that the email address has to be changed to that user. Im just wondering on how to automate this because its really time consuming. Hope that makes sense.